# how can i customize the way tinymce fixes broken html? particularly lists?

Tags: html, filter, tinymce, html-lists

I have end-users who created html like this:

```
<ol>
      <li>some text</li>
      <li>some more text</li>
      <div>a div in the wrong spot</div>
      <li>the last line of text</li>
</ol>
```

Tinymce turns it into something like this:

```
<ol>
      <li>some text</li>
      <li>some more text</li>
</ol>
      <div>a div in the wrong spot</div>
<ol>
      <li>the last line of text</li>
</ol>
```

This is a problem because sometimes it restarts the  numbering, and sometimes it doesn't restart numbering (start="3") but the formatting is always messed up.

How can I force tinymce to append the `<div>` inside of the previous `<li>`?

I've tried setting fix_list_elements to false, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still have not found an exact answer, but there is a sufficient workaround. Using the `valid_children` TinyMCE option.

```
{
  valid_children : "+ul[div],+ol[div]"
}
```

This allows for granularity in letting invalid HTML remain unfixed.